# Map Fragment .Как передать и где создать координаты места из списка

Tags: android-fragment, google-maps-api

Имеется список из которого по нажатию на пункт необходимо передать данные(название или координаты) в MapFragment. Не могу разобраться с реализацией этого действия.
И где хранить массив с координатами?

Код  класса с массивом.

class MosOblClass {

```
private String nameOblMos;
private int imageId;
private String coordinator;

static final MosOblClass[] mosObl = {
        new MosOblClass("Рузское водохранилище", "geo:36.051622,122.310075",R.drawable.flat_19),
        new MosOblClass("Можайское водохранилище", "geo:56.051622 37.310075",R.drawable.flat_12),
        new MosOblClass("Озеро Морозово", "geo:56.051622 37.310075", R.drawable.flat_13),
        new MosOblClass("Другое водохранилище", "geo:56.051622 37.310075", R.drawable.flat_10),
        new MosOblClass("Другое водохранилище", "geo:56.051622 37.310075", R.drawable.flat_11),
        new MosOblClass("Другое водохранилище", "geo:56.051622 37.310075", R.drawable.flat_12),
        new MosOblClass("Другое водохранилище", "geo:56.051622 37.310075", R.drawable.flat_13),
        new MosOblClass("Другое водохранилище", "geo:56.051622 37.310075", R.drawable.flat_14),
        new MosOblClass("Другое водохранилище", "geo:56.051622 37.310075", R.drawable.flat_15),
        new MosOblClass("Другое водохранилище", "geo:56.051622 37.310075", R.drawable.flat_17),
        new MosOblClass("Другое водохранилище", "geo:56.051622 37.310075", R.drawable.flat_18),
        new MosOblClass("Другое водохранилище", "geo:56.051622 37.310075", R.drawable.flat_19),

};


private MosOblClass(String nameOblMos,String coordinator, int imageId) {
    this.nameOblMos = nameOblMos;
    this.imageId = imageId;
    this.coordinator = coordinator;


}

public String getName() {
    return nameOblMos;
}


public String getCoordinator() {
    return coordinator;
}




public int getImageResourceId() {return imageId;
}
```

}

класс активити :

public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  OnMapReadyCallback {

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
GoogleMap map;
final String TAG = "myLogs";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync((OnMapReadyCallback) this);

    setTitle(getIntent().getStringExtra("name"));

}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    LatLng mesto = new LatLng(0,0);
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(mesto).title("mesto"));
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(mesto));
}
```

}

Comment: в активность ScrollingActivity отправляйте координаты для карты, а в ней уже открывается гугл карты с этими переданными данными, следовательно вам надо создать массив с координатами и отправлять в активность эти координаты, взяв их из массива, указав позицию нажатого итема как индекс

Comment: @Flippy есть массив с названиями мест. необходимо передать их. Отправлять их через intent или каким то другим способом? наведите на верное решение,запутался)

Comment: передавайте через intent --> mosObl[position]

Comment: @Flippy
adapter.setListener(new RecyclerAdapter.Listener() {
            public void onClick(int position) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ScrollingActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("adapterMessage",R.drawable.material_logo);
                intent.putExtra (MosOblClass[position]);
                getActivity().startActivity(intent);

Comment: @Flippy массив  отдельным классом у меня

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Слушатель должен быть примерно таким, не пойму где у вас находится массив, почему он в модели? Он должет быть во фрагменте или в активности

```
 adapter.setListener(new RecyclerAdapter.Listener() {
        public void onClick(int position) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ScrollingActivity.class);
           intent.putExtra("name", mosObl[position].getName);
            getActivity().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

В ScrollingActivity

```
setTitle(getIntent().getStringExtra("name"));
```

Таким же образом передаете координаты широты и долготы.

Открыть goole-maps:

```
String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "geo:%f,%f", latitude, longitude);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Таким образом открывает карты без передачи информации в них. Массив находится отдельным классом,а уже во фрагменте берутся данные из массива.

Comment: А я про карты и не писал)

Comment: Title передается и выводится название в заголовке активити,но вот как еедать название места в карты,не разобрался! помогите

Comment: Задайте другой вопрос, я отвечу., у вас проблема была с отправкой текста в активность, а сейчас ещё что-то.

Comment: Верные ответы выделяют галкой ;)

Comment: Хорошо)  текст передает,только не на кнопку fab))) а вопрос у меня состоит в том,что бы передать текст в гугл карты)

Comment: Это сделать нельзя. Вам надо раздобыть координаты широты и долготы и передать их в карты

Comment: ок. я добавлю их в массив с названиями этих мест ,добавлю еще одну переменную String coordinator. Как тогда их передать?)

Comment: Также, как и название места. В гугл карты передать? Дополнил ответ

Comment: Да, в карты Гугл Или другое стороннее приложение которое открывает карты.

Comment: Обновил ответ..

Comment: обновил вопрос) буду благодарен за его просмотр и если будет,то и совет)